# Manipulate text value of jQuery nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I selected all nodes on an HTML page like so:

```
var all = $('*');
```

I then traverse each node, checking to see if each has an associated text value:

```
var newDom = all.map((i, node) => {
  if ($(node).text()) {
     var temp = $(node).text() + 'a';
     $(node).text(temp);
  }
});
```

I ultimately want to view the manipulated DOM in the browser. Without the above manipulation, `all.html()` yields the exact webpage that was selected, as we would expect. Meanwhile, `newDom.html()` yields the following error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND on.ico on.ico:80
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:79:26)
```

At first glance, why might this not be working as I have it above?

Comment: What manipulation have you done? What result did you get? What did you expect? Why not post the code as a runnable snippet that displays your issue?

Comment: Hey @RobG thanks for the heads up, great advice. I updated the question as you suggested, hopefully you can offer some insight now!

Comment: Note that [*.text*](https://api.jquery.com/text/) will "*Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants…*" so you will get a lot of redundancy if there are any descendants. Also, setting the *text* will wipe out the existing content, including any HTML.

Comment: @RobG that's really good to know, I'm sure that is a problem I would have had to deal with eventually. Perhaps I should use contents()

Comment: If you want to change only text, you need to think very carefully about what you're doing. Plain javascript might be best for that so you can iterate over just text nodes within elements with a simple DOM traversal function.

Comment: @RobG _"Also, setting the text will wipe out the existing content, including any HTML."_ Does `.text()` call remove `.innerHTML` of element ?

Comment: @guest271314—no idea, it's supposed to emulate the behaviour of *textContent*, so it replaces the entire content of an element with the supplied value (if it's a string). It could be just `element.textContent = suppliedValue.toString()`. Like many jQuery methods, it's overloaded so the behaviour depends on the type of the value passed to it.

Comment: @RobG Do not believe `.text()` gets or sets `.innerHTML`. Though does return content of `<script>` elements

Comment: @guest271314—"*…replaces the entire content…*" means it replaces everything. **All** nodes are removed and replaced with a single text node, read the source: `this.empty().append( (this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode( text ) )`. Of course all that can be replaced with the very much simpler `element.textContent = text`.

Comment: @RobG Interesting. Both approaches appear to return same result http://plnkr.co/edit/zL2J0qna8FC1Oh8wqNfu?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314—jQuery has all that cruft because it rolls its own event model (look at what *empty* does), otherwise it's totally unnecessary.

Comment: @RobG Yes, agree jQuery is not necessary to get, set text of element.

Comment: I guess it was wrong to assume that jQuery was the *easy* solution.  @RobG you mentioned earlier that it may be easier to use plain JS to iterate over just text nodes within elements with a simple DOM traversal function, but I don't know of an easy, standard one off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no selector for text nodes, however you can write a recursive function to get them all as an array based on a root node. Then you can loop over the array and do stuff to the text nodes, e.g.

```js
/* Return all text nodes that are descendents of root as an array
** @param {DOMElement} root - node to start from, defaults to document.body
** @returns {Array} array of all text nodes that are descendents of root
*/
function getTextNodes(root) {
  var root = root || document.body;
  var textNodes = [];
  // Don't process text inside these nodes
  var elementsToIgnore = {'script':true};

  if (root && root.nodeType == 1) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(root.childNodes || [root], function(node) {

      if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName && !(node.tagName.toLowerCase() in elementsToIgnore)) {
        textNodes = textNodes.concat(getTextNodes(node));

      } else if (node.nodeType == 3){
        textNodes.push(node);
      }
    });
  } else if (root.nodeType == 3) {
    textNodes.push(root);
  }
  return textNodes;
}
```

```html
 <p>Here is some text</p>
 <ol>
   <li>List item 1
   <li>List item 2
     <ol>
       <li>List item 2.1
       <li>List item 2.3
     </ol>
   <li>List item 3
  </ol>
  <textarea>Gets text in here too</textarea>
  <br>

  <button onclick="getTextNodes().forEach(function(node){node.data = node.data.replace(/s/g,'$')})">Replace all 's' with $</button>
```